# Adding top level items in the admin menu that link to a post

Tags: menus, admin

I'm trying to add top level menu items (not sub-menus) to my WP admin menu that link to edit a post. The reason for it, is that I have different sections and custom post types, so I'd like to have items in the menu that work like shortcuts.

So far I was able to create one using the code below, which isn't mine, but I adapted it. It works fine for just one item, but I'd like to create more (two or three) and I haven't been able to get it right.

```
function add_custom_menu_item(){
    add_menu_page( 'Slider Menu', 'Slider', 'manage_options', 'page_slug', 'function', 'dashicons-images-alt2', 6 );
} 
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_custom_menu_item' );

function custom_menu_item_redirect() {

    $menu_redirect = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : false;

    if($menu_redirect == 'page_slug' ) {
       wp_safe_redirect( home_url('/wp-admin/post.php?post=1883&action=elementor') );
       exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_menu_item_redirect', 1 );
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Carlos. You could just copy the `add_menu_page()` line for the other top-level links you want to create. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/

Comment: Hello. Yes, thank you! I know that copying that  `add_menu_page()` line allows me to create more top level items. What I don't know is how to add different redirects to each one of them.

Comment: I see. Please check my answer and let me know if that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to add different redirects to each one of them

You can do an *if-elseif-elseif...* like this:

```
if ( condition 1 ) {
    // do something
} elseif ( condition 2 ) {
    // do something else
} elseif ( condition 3 ) {
    // do something else
}
```

So let's say you created *three top-level admin menu items*:

```
add_menu_page( 'Slider Menu', 'Slider', 'manage_options', 'page_slug', 'function', 'dashicons-images-alt2', 6 );
add_menu_page( 'Page Title', 'Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'page_slug2', 'function' );
add_menu_page( 'Page Title 2', 'Menu Title 2', 'manage_options', 'page_slug3', 'function' );
```

Then your *if-elseif-elseif...* would look something like this:

```
// For the "Slider" menu.
if ( $menu_redirect == 'page_slug' ) {
   wp_safe_redirect( admin_url( 'post.php?post=1883&action=elementor' ) );
   exit();
// For the "Menu Title" menu.
} elseif ( $menu_redirect == 'page_slug2' ) {
   wp_safe_redirect( 'URL here' );
   exit();
// For the "Menu Title 2" menu.
} elseif ( $menu_redirect == 'page_slug3' ) {
   wp_safe_redirect( 'URL here' );
   exit();
}
```

Btw, I think you should use [`admin_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/admin_url/) for getting the URL of an admin page. =)

Comment: That totally did it. Thanks Sally! I couldn't find much information on how to do this, so I hope your answer helps someone else too.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you! So, maybe you can [accept](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that answer?.. ;)

Comment: Hi, I'd like to modify the above code so it works both with the English and Spanish versions of my site. Right now the code is taking into account the 'page_slug' string to redirect the user to the desired page.  I wonder if there's a way to use the url as a string so depending on whether the user is on the _/es_ or _/en_ site, he's redirected appropriately.

Comment: On second though, I think a good approach could be to add the items for the Spanish version and then hide them based on whether the url is /es or /en. Any ideas on how to achieve that? Meaning I'd have two Slider items, but only one would be seen depending on language.

Comment: Hi @Carlos. I suggest you to post/ask a new question, and share its URL here. 